# One sided ideal in finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite dimensional $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra and $\mathcal{A}p$ a one-sided, non-self-adjoint left ideal. That is there exists $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$f_1pf_2\not\in\mathcal{A}p.$$

Can the "not a right ideal"ness of $\mathcal{A}p$ be exhibited by a projection $q=f_1=f_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**.  If $p$ and $f$ are projections in a C*-algebra such that $fpf$ is idempotent, then $p$ and $f$ commute.

*Proof*. We have
$$
  (pf-fp)^3=
  (pfpf - fpf - pfp + fpfp)(pf-fp) = $$$$ =
  pfpfpf - fpfpf - pfpf + fpfpf  - pfpfp + fpfp + pfpfp - fpfpfp =  $$$$ =
  pfpf - fpf - pfpf + fpf  - pfpfp + fpfp + pfpfp - fpfp = 0.
  $$
Since $pf-fp$ is skew-adjoint,  it follows that $pf-fp=0$, so $p$ and $f$ commute. $\qquad\square$

**Proposition**.
Let $A$ be a C*-algebra generated by projections and let $p$ be a fixed projection in $A$.  If
$$
  fpf\in Ap,
  $$
for every
projection $f$, then $p$ is central (and hence $Ap$ is a two sided ideal).

*Proof*.
If $fpf \in  Ap$,  then $fpf = fpfp$.  Multiplying on the right by $f$ gives  $fpf = fpfpf$, which means that $fpf$ is idempotent,  and hence $f$ and $p$
commute by the Lemma.  Since $f$ is an arbitrary projection in  $A$, and $A$ is generated by projections, then $p$ is central. $\qquad\square$

Comment: Lovely and more general too. Since I posted I was thinking about setting a basis on one factor where $p$ is diagonal with zero from index $i$ on. Then in index $i-1$ to $i$ take the projection $q$ of all $1/2$. Then $qpq$ is the matrix of all quarters starting in the $i-1$ to $i$ indices so falling outside the ideal; but yours is way better 

Comment: Another way to prove the Lemma in my answer is to use the characterization of representations of pairs of projections: if $p$ and $f$ do not commute, then there is an irreducible representation of $C^*(p,f)$ mapping $pf-fp$ to something nonzero. One then reaches a contradiction by analyzing the image of the *projection* $fpf$.